# Add item to list in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, asp-classic

I'm facing trouble while adding item to list in jQuery, here is the syntax what i follow. both are not working.

```
$("myList")[0].options.add(new Option("ListText", value)); //does not work

  $("myList").append($('<option>', {
                 text: "ListText",
                 value: value
    })); //does not work

 $("myList").append(new Option("ListText", value)); //does not work.
```

Here how my code looks

```
<select id="myList" class="DropDownList Test" name="List">                                           
    <option value="selectid" selected="selected">--Please Select--</option> 
    <option value="test1">a</option> 
    <option value="test2">b</option> 
    <option value="test3">c</option>               
</select>
```

Lets imaging i m doing something like this, if i do also it fails.

```
function updateTheList(ListID, value, position) {

        switch (position) {
             case '1':
                 $(ListID).append(new Option("Text", value));
                break; 
        } //what is wrong with this syntax

    }

if ($(Name+ "-ListID").is(':visible')) {
            updateTheList($(Name+ "-ListID"), value, position);
        } // it does not work
```

Kindly tell me the correct way.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the `#` hash on the jquery selector. Use this

```
$("#myList").append($('<option>', {
             text: "ListText",
             value: value
}));
```

To insert at a specific position use this. The main thing you were doing wrong above was passing a Jquery object into the function and then wrapping it in another jquery object.

```
function updateTheList(listId, text, value, position) {

    $(listId + ' option:eq(' + position + ')')
       .after('<option value=\"' + value + '\">' + text + '</option>');
}

if ($('#SomeListId').is(':visible')) {
    updateTheList('#SomeListId', 'Some text', 'Some value', 2);
}
```

Also try to stick with naming conventions. use camelCase for methods and properties, PascalCase for objects.

Comment: Awesome, your trick worked. My problem was ID.. thanks lot. But one thing i want to know like, how can i add the item at particular position. pls suggest me

Comment: Your welcome, you could try this: `$('#myList option:eq(3)').after('<option value="something">Something</option>');` which would insert after the 4th element in a list of option DOM elements.

Comment: your  syntax is not matching with answered one, could u pls explain clearly in answer.. it will be useful for all..

Comment: yes, inserting at a particular position requires a different function. Hence a different syntax. The append function only appends at the end.

Comment: In append, the "Something" will be my text right. i tried to modify above way, it didnt worked :(

Comment: I've just tried both way and it works fine. Make sure you choose an index that is within the length of options if you use `:eq(index)`.

Comment: I guess you forgot to add 'option' in the edited question. & provide a space after option i.e like this  

$(listId + ' option:eq(' + position + ')').after('<option value=\"' + value + '\">' + 'name' + '</option>');

Answer (score 6):

You selector is wrong. It should be `$("#myList")` to select an element by ID.

You can read more about it the [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Comment: If it is like this then,  $(Name+ "-ListID").append(new Option("Text", value); it wont work :(

Comment: @LLL, I can't read minds, please clarify your comment. I can't see any usage of `"-ListID"` in your HTML

Comment: thanks for ur help. the problem was related to ID, we got to select the list id, rather i was using DIV ID :P... thanks fr ur help

Answer (score 1):

2 things-

1. You missed out the `#` to select with an ID.
2. Try with the `<option />`, not `<option>`.

   $('#mySelect').append($("", {
           value: key,
           text: value
       }));

This should work.

Comment: how to insert at particular position, pls help me